# How to: Check if a ListView is scrollable/larger than screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to determine whether a ListView is scrollable or displaying items larger than the screen.

This is because I would like a show a toast message to inform the user to scroll down but only if the ListView's children are scrollable e.g. on some larger devices the list may not actually need to scroll in order to display an image but on smaller devices a large image inside of a ListView may be scrollable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get `ListView`'s content height by accessing `controller.position.maxScrollExtent` on `controller`'s listener.

```dart
final ScrollController controller = ScrollController();

@override
void initState() {
  _controller.addListener(_scrollListener);
 
  super.initState();
}

@override
void dispose() {
  _controller?.removeListener(_scrollListener);
  _controller.dispose();
 
  super.dispose();
}

void _scrollListener() {
  // you can access the height of ListView content using maxScrollExtent
  print(_controller.position.maxScrollExtent);

  // if you wanna get once you can directly removeListener
  // _controller.removeListener(_scrollListener);
}
```

You need to attach `_controller` to `ListView`'s controller

Comment: how can we find out whether scrolling is started with the value `_controller.position.maxScrollExtent` ? @Ampersanda

Answer (score 0):

Take screen size form `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` first as a reference for the screen size.

Then now check this reference size with the height of the `listView`,  and set a `bool` variable `true` or `false` to show the `toast`

---

Example:

`double screenSize=MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`

If your ListView has one tile of height 30.0 including top and bottom the margins for the tile. and there are 10 tiles. Then the `ListView` height would be 300.0

Now if the screen size is greater than 300.0 then there is no need to show the `toast` and if it is smaller then show the `toast`

Comment: I don't think this is a practical answer, as there may be other widgets in the screen with unknown heights

Comment: @HassanM.Said I guess that's why it is not marked as an answer XD.